# Conan fails to link agains installed library because its name has different letter size then required

Tags: windows, case-insensitive, conan

The problem is that I have s Protobuf library on my corporate arrtyfactory which we all use,
but it so happened that now I need grpc. So I added
`grpc/1.26.0@inexorgame/stable`
line to my conanfile.txt and when I try to run the installation scrip it gives me the following error:
ERROR: Requested 'protobuf/3.9.1@bincrafters/stable' but found case incompatible 'Protobuf'
I have seen a mailing list somwhre about what seemed to be the same problem and it seemed to me the conan devs told that there is nothing to be done here. But maybe I misread things and there is a way to have two different packages: 'Protobuf' and 'protobuf' tha the same time on windows?

Comment: Conan packages are moving to https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index repo, and packages are named without "user/channel", like ``protobuf/3.11.4`` https://conan.io/center/protobuf/3.11.4. These packages are also learning to use the upstream package names, including casing, the feature has been released, and packages from ConanCenter are being updated. I suggest to try to move to these new packages (without user/channel) because they are way more maintained and supported.

Comment: Thanks for the suggesion, but It does not have grpc (

Comment: You might try to open an issue in github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index requesting it, so contributors might read it and prioritize if possible